# elasticsearch facets OR filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem with my elasticsearch DSL, in that when using facet navigation, when I apply my facet filter, the next set of results don't include any further facets, even though I've asked for them.

When I do the initial search, I get the results I want back:

```
{
"sort": {
    "_score": {},
    "salesQuantity": {
        "order": "asc"
    }
},
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "match": {
                "categoryTree": "D01"
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "term": {
                "publicwebEnabled": true,
                "parentID": 0
            }
        }
    }
},
"facets": {
    "delivery_locations": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "delivery_locations",
            "all_terms": true
        }
    },
    "categories": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "categoryTree",
            "all_terms": true
        }
    },
    "collectable": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "collectable",
            "all_terms": true
        }
    }
},
"from": 0,
"size": 12}
```

When I then apply a filter like so, the results I get back do not include the facets:

```
{
"sort": {
    "_score": {},
    "salesQuantity": {
        "order": "asc"
    }
},
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "match": {
                "categoryTree": "D01"
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "term": {
                "publicwebEnabled": true,
                "parentID": 0
            },
            "or": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "Retail_Price": {
                            "to": "49.99",
                            "from": "0"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
"facets": {
    "delivery_locations": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "delivery_locations",
            "all_terms": true
        }
    },
    "categories": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "categoryTree",
            "all_terms": true
        }
    },
    "collectable": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "collectable",
            "all_terms": true
        }
    }
},
"from": 0,
"size": 12}
```

**NOTE**, I'm adding the OR filter above - because users may choose multiple price ranges to filter on.

Am I doing something wrong?

I want the new facets returned as altering the prices would obviously alter the facet counts of the other facets...

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same thing. When my query block contains a "filtered" part I dont get any facets back in the result

Answer (score 0):

Add the original term-filter inside the or-filter, or add another boolean filter to wrap your whole filter inside a boolean expression. I dont think you can add the two filters just by comma-separating them like that.

Comment: Well, the query works. I get the results I was expecting - but the returning JSON doesn't have a facets object (at ALL).

Comment: I'll do a little more investigating